# Error installing psycopg2 on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: python, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, psycopg2

Hi i am trying to install psycopg2 on Mac 10.6. After i install i get this error when i try to import

```
import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol  not found: _PQbackendPID
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

I got the source from http://initd.org/psycopg/download/ and tried to build from source using setup/easy_install with the value for pg_config set to **/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_config** in setup.cfg

I tried all these alternatives and nothing seems to work

http://blog.timc3.com/2010/08/20/psycopg2-os-x-_pqbackendpid/

http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/11/11/links-about-building-psycopg-mac-os-x/

Any ideas whats happening here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](http://stubblog.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/installing-psycopg2-on-osx/), psycopg2 seems must work in 32bit mode on MacOSX